# Grails 3 parse YAML into ConfigObject

Tags: grails, groovy, yaml

I'm updating a Grails plugin to Grails 3. The code is using `ConfigSlurper.parse()` to parse a Groovy config script into a `ConfigObject`.
It appears the default config style for Grails 3 is YAML, so is there a similar utility to parse YAML into a ConfigObject?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

ConfigObject is only an intermediate class in Grails 3, used to create a PropertySource from Groovy config files. The type of the config is now a `org.grails.config.PropertySourcesConfig`.

I'm not sure if there's a more direct way to do this, but here's some working code that will build a `PropertySourcesConfig` from a YAML file:

```
import org.grails.config.PropertySourcesConfig
import org.grails.config.yaml.YamlPropertySourceLoader
import org.springframework.core.io.FileSystemResource

String name = 'my yaml file'
def resource = new FileSystemResource(new File('/path/to/foo.yml'))
def mapPropertySource = new YamlPropertySourceLoader().load(
      name, resource, null/*profile*/)
def conf = new PropertySourcesConfig(mapPropertySource.getSource())
```

Answer (score 0):

If YAML is parsed into a `Map` then you can call [`putAll`](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/gapi/groovy/util/ConfigObject.html#putAll%28java.util.Map%29) on an instance of `ConfigObject`:

```
def cfg = new ConfigObject()
cfg.putAll(yml)
println cfg.some.value
```